# invalid arguments candidates are void destroyWindow(const? &)

Tags: c++, eclipse, opencv, ubuntu

I am using Eclipse. After I upgrade it using "Help -> Check for updates", my codes have these errors:

```
invalid arguments candidates are void destroyWindow(const? &)
invalid arguments candidates are cv::Mat imread(const? &, int)
```

See this image: [image]

But when I run my codes, it still works fine. The image window can be created and also the image can be shown and then window can be destroyed. So what's wrong about my eclipse ?